# Are VSTS NuGet package feeds geo-distributed

Tags: azure-artifacts

We'd like to use VSTS feeds as a source for geo-distributed service fabric app deployments. If the feeds aren't distributed, well need to first distribute the package to multiple data centers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS feeds are currently served out of a single Microsoft Azure region per account. We have been looking at mechanisms for better supporting geographically-distributed teams, but don't have anything to announce at this time.